# database design - sales, products, customers, persons and organizations

Tags: join, schema, best-practices

I am trying to model a system where you can have persons or organizations as customers.

persons or organizations can also have other sub-types like employees, suppliers and other types in the future.
All of these types can have multiple phone numbers, emails, addresses and bank accounts.

At the moment I solved it this way:
[image]

so I created a polymorphic type that looks like this:

person/organization ----> contact <--- customer/supplier

now all my other tables that every type can hav, like addresses, emails etc. just have to point to contacts and do need multiple foreign keys

Here are my questions:

- is there a better way doing that?
- is it okay to have such a lot of subtypes even if multiple JOINs are needed?
- when would you denormalize and use values to determine "types"?

(I will ask my sales-items questions later :)

thanks in advanced!